# return input field with qoute values not working

Tags: php, html, encoding, quotes, addslashes

I have a function that creates input fields.

```
$string = '<input type="' . $field_type . '" class="form-control" id="' . $field_name . '" name="' . $field_name . '" value="' . $field_value . '">';
return $string
```

$field_value holds a string with qoutes.
var_dump result of $field_value:

```
string(19) ""Open Sans",Verdana"
```

When I look at the source inside the Developer Tools of Chrome the result is:

```
 <input type="text" class="form-control" id="themesettings[main_body_font_family]" name="themesettings[main_body_font_family]" value="" open="" sans",verdana"="">
```

I have tried addslashes($field_value) but that returns:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="themesettings[main_body_font_family]" name="themesettings[main_body_font_family]" value="\" open="" sans\",verdana"="">
```

Both results are not correct/working. How can I make the input value work correctly with qoutes.

Comment: [The Great Escapism (Or: What You Need To Know To Work With Text Within Text)](http://kunststube.net/escapism/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are trying to do is to mask the quotes. Masking in HTML is not done by adding `\` or something but by replacing it with a so called HTML entity. Thus you have to replace all quotes by `&quot;`. You can easily do it using PHP native function [htmlentities()](http://php.net/manual/function.htmlentities.php).

Comment: Thanx didn't think of that function, sometimes you overthink problems while the answer is simple.

Answer (score 1):

Use `htmlentities($field_value)` it will convert " to html entities

```
<?php 
 $field_value_converted = htmlentities($field_value);
?>

<input ... value="<?php echo $field_value_converted ?>" >
```

See more about `htmlentities()` function abilities here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php OR http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_htmlentities.asp